# New to Javascript - Live Server for VSCode not showing blank page for blank script

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I'm new to javascript and coding in general, I'm not sure if it's to do with Live Server or not, but in my first few practice scripts, Live server was working perfectly, if I had nothing in the html it would show a blank page but I could access the components of the script in the console as normal. The last few times I opened a new window in VS Code, the Live Server tab at the bottom didn't appear, and I found out online to press shift+P and I could get it from there, however, ever since I started doing that, I've no longer been seeing a blank page, I've been seeing this (see image) and the correct code isn't appearing in the console. Could someone please help me with this? Thanks!

[What I'm seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4ClE.png)

Comment: Can you show us the index.html you're using? (paste it into the question and wrap it in `\`\`\``)

Comment: That was actually the problem, I didn't have the source element pointing at the right script, thank you!